# Taking 2 columns with equal value x or differing values x/y to create a 3rd column with value x

Tags: python, pandas

I have df

```
technologies = {'Writer1': ['Spark', 'PySpark', 'Hadoop', 'Python'],
 'Location1': ['LA', 'RIV', 'CHV', 'LA'],
 'Area1': ['L', 'R', 'C', 'L'],
 'Writer2': ['Spark', 'Dil', 'Chee', 'Python'],
 'Location2': ['RIV', 'RIV', 'LA', 'RIV'],
 'Area2': ['R', 'R', 'L', 'R'],}
df = pd.DataFrame(technologies)
```

I want to create a new Location column indexing location 1/2 but only taking locations in Area1/2 "R" and "C"

So I would want

```
technologies = {'Writer1': ['Spark', 'PySpark', 'Hadoop', 'Python'],
 'Location1': ['LA', 'RIV', 'CHV', 'LA'],
 'Area1': ['L', 'R', 'C', 'L'],
 'Writer2': ['Spark', 'Dil', 'Chee', 'Python'],
 'Location2': ['RIV', 'RIV', 'LA', 'RIV'],
 'Area2': ['R', 'R', 'L', 'R'],
 'Location3': ['RIV', 'RIV', 'CHV', 'RIV']}
```

Is this possible?  I am stuck and can't think of what would work for so many requirements.

Any help appreciated  Thank you
===EDIT
Sorry I did not include vital detail.  I would like the location to index with the Writer1/2.  For example if I index PySpark with RIV, I also want Dil to index with RIV.  The code should not bypass a Writer if they both are in RIV or CHV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a generic method to use with any number of Location/Area pairs (in order), you can use:

```py
lst = ['R', 'C']
df = pd.DataFrame(technologies)
df2 = (df.filter(like='Location')
      .where(df.filter(like='Area').isin(lst).values)
      )
df['Location3'] = df2.stack().groupby(level=0).first()
# first() for first value as preference if many
```

or, using a MultiIndex:

```py
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.columns.str.extract('(\w+)(\d+)'))
df2 = df.set_axis(idx, axis=1)
df['LocationX'] = (df2['Location'].where(df2['Area'].isin(lst)).stack()
                   .groupby(level=0).first()
                   )
```

output:

```
   Writer1 Location1 Area1 Writer2 Location2 Area2 Location3
0    Spark        LA     L   Spark       RIV     R       RIV
1  PySpark       RIV     R     Dil        LA     L       RIV
2   Hadoop       CHV     C    Chee        LA     L       CHV
3   Python        LA     L  Python       RIV     R       RIV
```

##### duplicates

if there are multiple possibilities and you want to keep all

as concatenated values:

```py
lst = ['R', 'C']
df = pd.DataFrame(technologies)
df2 = (df.filter(like='Location')
      .where(df.filter(like='Area').isin(lst).values)
      )
df['LocationX'] = df2.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
```

output:

```
   Writer1 Location1 Area1 Writer2 Location2 Area2 LocationX
0    Spark        LA     L   Spark       RIV     R       RIV
1  PySpark       RIV     R     Dil       RIV     R   RIV,RIV
2   Hadoop       CHV     C    Chee        LA     L       CHV
3   Python        LA     L  Python       RIV     R       RIV
```

or, as multiple rows:

```
lst = ['R', 'C']
df = pd.DataFrame(technologies)
df2 = (df.filter(like='Location')
      .where(df.filter(like='Area').isin(lst).values)
      )
df = df.join(df2.stack().rename('LocationX').droplevel(1))
```

output:

```
   Writer1 Location1 Area1 Writer2 Location2 Area2 LocationX
0    Spark        LA     L   Spark       RIV     R       RIV
1  PySpark       RIV     R     Dil       RIV     R       RIV
1  PySpark       RIV     R     Dil       RIV     R       RIV
2   Hadoop       CHV     C    Chee        LA     L       CHV
3   Python        LA     L  Python       RIV     R       RIV
```

Comment: @midwstchnk this mostly makes sense if you have several pairs, otherwise the other method is more straightforward (that was also my initial approach) ;)

Comment: im sorry but i forgot a vital issue which I noticed after running the code examples provided. I would like the Writer 1 and 2 to both index with the location even if they are both RIV and/or CHV. At the moment if the first writer is RIV the second Writer will be inadvertently left out. Is there a solution to this conundrum? @mozway

Comment: @midwstchnk what would be the output in this case?

Comment: for my MultiIndex example you could use `df['Location3'] = df2.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)` to get "RIV,RIV" for index 1

Comment: for multiple rows: `out = df.join(df2.stack().rename('LocationX').droplevel(1))`

Comment: df['LocationX'] = df2.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(','.join): i'm getting invalid syntax at the df.    i'm putting my dataframe in front of the column.

Comment: The bit of code above doesn't have a syntax issue, are you sure it's not coming from previous lines?

Comment: you are right, i found the syntax error.  pesky ) @mozway

Comment: So did it all work as you want?

Answer (score 2):

Replace non `R,C` values in `Location1/2` columns to missing values by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and then replace missing values from `s1` by `s2` in [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(technologies)

s1 = df['Location1'].where(df['Area1'].isin(['R','C']))  
s2 = df['Location2'].where(df['Area2'].isin(['R','C']))
df['Location3'] = s1.fillna(s2)
print (df)
   Writer1 Location1 Area1 Writer2 Location2 Area2 Location3
0    Spark        LA     L   Spark       RIV     R       RIV
1  PySpark       RIV     R     Dil        LA     L       RIV
2   Hadoop       CHV     C    Chee        LA     L       CHV
3   Python        LA     L  Python       RIV     R       RIV
```

Solution for multiple values - if match both values are joined:

```
technologies = {'Writer1': ['Spark', 'PySpark', 'Hadoop', 'Python'],
 'Location1': ['LA', 'RIV', 'CHV', 'RIV'],
 'Area1': ['L', 'R', 'C', 'L'],
 'Writer2': ['Spark', 'Dil', 'Chee', 'Python'],
 'Location2': ['RIV', 'RIV', 'RIV', 'RIV'],
 'Area2': ['R', 'R', 'L', 'R'],}
df = pd.DataFrame(technologies)



s1 = df['Location1'].add(', ').where(df['Area1'].isin(['R','C']), '')  
s2 = df['Location2'].where(df['Area2'].isin(['R','C']), '')

df['Location3'] = s1.add(s2).str.strip(', ')
print (df)
   Writer1 Location1 Area1 Writer2 Location2 Area2 Location3
0    Spark        LA     L   Spark       RIV     R       RIV
1  PySpark       RIV     R     Dil       RIV     R  RIV, RIV
2   Hadoop       CHV     C    Chee       RIV     L       CHV
3   Python       RIV     L  Python       RIV     R       RIV
```

Comment: if i have blanks do i need to fill na first also?

Comment: @midwstchnk - Can you explain more? `if i have blanks` - in input data? In ouput?

Comment: oh for example if Location has a nan for location 1 but not location 2

Comment: @midwstchnk - then solution working too.

Comment: im sorry but i forgot a vital issue which I noticed after running the code example you provided.  I would like the Writer 1 and 2 to both index with the location even if they are both RIV and/or CHV.  At the moment if the first writer is RIV there where be no na to fill so the second Writer will be inadvertently left out.  Is there a solution to this conundrum? @jezrael